# How to create a transparent full screen dialog on top of activity - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a transparent full screen dialog on top of activity. I have tried following this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9627) but solution doesn't work.

**In short , what I need is:**

- full screen dialog.
- transparent background except for the widget I use for the dialog

here's my code:

> To open dialog

```
void onNextBtnClick(){
    var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
        new GenreDialogUI(),fullscreenDialog: true
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
}
```

> For Dialog view

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class HolePuncherPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static final clearPaint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.transparent,
    ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;

  const HolePuncherPainter();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
        new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height), clearPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class GenreDialogUI extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _GenreDialogUI createState() => new _GenreDialogUI();
}

class _GenreDialogUI extends State<GenreDialogUI>  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: addAppbar(),
      body: new CustomPaint(
        painter: HolePuncherPainter(),
        child: new Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: UtilCommonWidget.addText('Transparent Dialog', Colors.red, 22.0, 1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908187/how-to-make-a-full-screen-dialog-in-flutter

Comment: You can use the `ModalRoute` like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908876/4493738

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
        return YourFullScreenAlertDialog()
    }
));
```

YourFullScreenAlertDialog could be a widget that has a background color, Colors.transparent, like [@creativecreatorormaybenot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509751) mentioned earlier.

Comment: could you please let me know how to exit from YourFullScreenAlertDialog()?
In my case, the "YourFullScreenAlertDialog()" is a stateless widget and is not being popped when enabling "barrierDismissible: true" in PageRouteBuilder (while the docs had mentioned that it'll pop it out)

Answer (score 31):

For me the following worked:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: Center(
      // Aligns the container to center
      child: Container(
        // A simplified version of dialog.
        width: 100.0,
        height: 56.0,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text('jojo'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my implementation.

From first screen call this.

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const NoInternetScreen(),
                  opaque: false,  ---->> opacity should be false
                  fullscreenDialog: true));
```

And in next screen set background color with opacity.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: white.withOpacity(0.85),

......
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqqSU.png)

Answer (score 2):

**Screenshot (`showGeneralDialog`):**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
      onPressed: () {
        showGeneralDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierColor: Colors.black38,
          barrierLabel: 'Label',
          barrierDismissible: true,
          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text('Dialog', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 40),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```