# How to make a full screen dialog in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a full screen dialog box. Dialog box background must be opaque. 
Here is an example:
[image]

How to make like this in Flutter?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the `Navigator` to push a semi-transparent [`ModalRoute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TutorialOverlay extends ModalRoute<void> {
  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5);

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
    // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
      child: SafeArea(
        child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'This is a nice overlay',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text('Dismiss'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
      BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    // You can add your own animations for the overlay content
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: animation,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}


// Example application:
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(TutorialOverlay());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => _showOverlay(context),
            child: Text('Show Overlay'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Working Solution, thanks, Can you please know me how to call `setState();`, this method not working for update widget or is there any other way to update widget?

Comment: `setState` in which particular widget? `TestPage`? or inside the overlay?

Comment: It would be great if the answer could be slightly updated on how to use setState from that new ModalRoute class.

Comment: can I get direction of animation from bottom to top??

Comment: hello, i want it if scrolling down the page will go back .. how with ur same code

Answer (score 88):

Well here is my implementation which is quite straightforward.

from first screen

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) =>
        RedeemConfirmationScreen()));
```

at 2nd screen

```
class RedeemConfirmationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85), // this is the main reason of transparency at next screen. I am ignoring rest implementation but what i have achieved is you can see.
.....
  );
 }
}
```

and here are the results.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to show a clicked list item completely visible with this overlay modal?

Comment: since in flutter everything is a widget, so You can create whatever you want inside this ,

Comment: @MuhammadAdil How did you get this type of image?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij there is no image required for making a transparent dialog like screen. you just have to set opacity of the Main widget in new screen.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant this iphone xr frame

Comment: when you run the application at iOS simulator, you can move cursor on it, tap on it so simulator window get selected and then press cmd+shift+4 and keeping cursor on the simulator press the "SPACEBAR" and then click on the simulator. You will get a screenshot of whole simulator. @PhaniRithvij

Comment: Oh, so it's an ios thing. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yes you can take such screenshots in macbook, and same screenshot can be taken for android app too if you are running at android emulator. Taking screenshot in such way is behaviour of Mac OS.

Comment: Hi, so umm, how did you get it go away, I tried Navigator.pop(context) and that did not work

Comment: @Riz-waan it works same. Are you seeing any exception after pressing button ?

Comment: If you want to call `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` from a `build` method, then make sure you delay the execution of the `push` call until `build` has finished, by wrapping the call in a callback, then passing it to `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(callback)`.

Answer (score 74):

#### Screenshot (Flutter's native dialog)

[image]

Call this method to show the dialog in fullscreen.

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.6), // Background color
  barrierDismissible: false,
  barrierLabel: 'Dialog',
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  pageBuilder: (context, __, ___) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: SizedBox.expand(child: FlutterLogo()),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox.expand(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text('Dismiss'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Great: This one is better than other answers...Just to know, For what do you add `barrierLabel`?

Comment: @bloodloss thats just mandatory string you need to provide for voice accessibility feature.

Comment: @BISTech This is cosmetics for screen readers

Answer (score 31):

Note: This answer does not discuss making the modal transparent, but is an answer is for the stated question of "How to make a full screen dialog in flutter?".  Hopefully this helps other that find this question through a search like I did, that don't need a transparent modal.

Create your modal dialog class:

```
class SomeDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dialog Magic'),
      ),
      body: new Text("It's a Dialog!"),
    );
  }
}
```

In the class that needs to open the dialog, add something like this:

```
void openDialog() {
  Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new SomeDialog();
    },
    fullscreenDialog: true));
}
```

If `fullscreenDialog` above is `true`, then the app bar will have an "x" close button. If `false`, it will have a "<-" back arrow.

If you need to get the result of a dialog action, add a button to your dialog that returns a value when popping the navigation stack.  Something like this:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator
    .of(context)
    .pop(new MyReturnObject("some value");
}
```

then in your class opening the dialog, do capture the results with something like this:

```
void openDialog() async {
  MyReturnObject results = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<MyReturnObject>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new SomeDialog();
    },
    fullscreenDialog: true));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I see white screen with items on them. Not transparent

Comment: I mean, it does ask for a "dialog box background must be opaque.", so this answer doesn't fit this question IMO (even though he meant PARTIALLY opaque).

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella, if you type "full screen dialog flutter" into Google, this page will be the first hit, which is why I came here. In the first paragraph above, he explicitly says the answer does not address the translucency part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `showGeneralDialog` method with any widget extends from `Material` like `Scaffold`, `Card`, ..etc.

For example I am going to it with `Scaffold` like this:

```
showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: //Put your screen design here!
    ),
  );
```

And now you can set your design as a normal screen by using `Scaffold`.

**Note:** if you want to go back you can `Navigator` like this:

> Navigator.of(context).pop(null)

Answer (score 5):

## Different ways to show fullscreen dialog

#### A. Material Dialog

```dart
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  useSafeArea: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return const SomeScaffoldView();
  },
);
```

#### B. Cupertino Dialog

```dart
showCupertinoDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return const SomeScaffoldView();
  },
);
```

#### C. Custom Dialog

- Flutter uses this under-the-hood when displaying dialogs.
- Can customize transition animation with [`transitionBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher/transitionBuilder.html), here's a random guide [with example animations](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-dialogs-in-flutter-here-is-answer-492ea3a7262f).

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  pageBuilder: (
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return const SomeScaffoldView();
  },
);
```

#### Sample Scaffold View used in above snippets.

```dart
class SomeScaffoldView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Fullscreen Dialog'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Dialog Body')),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

It's now possible with [`Dialog.fullscreen`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog/Dialog.fullscreen.html) which implements the [Material 3's full screen dialogs](https://m3.material.io/components/dialogs/overview).

More details are available on the [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/112261/) and [the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104961).

Here is a [demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/4fda4cef416a20760cdd1aa86fba637a?id=4fda4cef416a20760cdd1aa86fba637a).

Comment: I think you have the wrong demo link. That goes to a counter app.

Comment: The dialog class documentation has a nice example using the normal constructor and fullscreen constructor: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Bill-- I updated the link now. Apparently, Dartpad requires appending an id at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AlertDialog` with zero `insetPadding` like below:

```cpp
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
          return AlertDialog(
            insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
              content: SizedBox.expand(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Sample type",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text(""))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

[RFlutter Alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) is super customizable and easy-to-use alert/popup dialogs for Flutter. You may create reusable alert styles or add buttons as much as you want with ease.

```
Alert(context: context, title: "RFLUTTER", desc: "Flutter is awesome.").show();
```

[RFlutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE8ZW.png)

It's easy to use! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your top-level widget with `Navigator` widget like so:

```
return Navigator(
        pages: [
          MaterialPage(
            child: MainScreen(
              child: widgets...
```

then call showDialog and because `useRootNavigator` is set to `true` in default it will use the root navigator that we added above the `MainScreen`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this if you use popular flutter library getx

[getx link](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

```
void showAlertDialogg(
    String body,
    String? confirmButtonText,
    String? cancelButtonText,
    Function(bool onConfirm, bool onCancel) clickEvent,
    {barrierDismissible = false}) {
  Get.dialog(
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextComponent(
          body,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          fontSize: textSmallFontSize,
          fontWeight: titleFontWeight,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        Row(
          //crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: OutlineButtonComponent(
                text: cancelButtonText,
                borderColor: kPrimaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.back();
                  clickEvent(false, true);
                },
                textColor: kPrimaryColor,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 8, 16),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ButtonComponent(
                text: confirmButtonText,
                buttonColor: kPrimaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.back();
                  clickEvent(true, false);
                },
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16,16, 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
    barrierColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.8),
    useSafeArea: true
  );
}
```

[image]

you can pas params as you want & call this method where you need it. it supports widget so you can setup the widget as you want.