# Guides/Walkthroughs Layer Implementation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How would you implement in Flutter a guiding layer on top of an actual screen. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not allow a simple answer.

You can use the [Highlighter Coach Mark plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/highlighter_coachmark) by Marina Kuznetsova.

Answer (score 3):

This is not trivial. Here are the required components:

First of all, you have to [open a transparent full screen dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908876/2461957). Alternatively you can directly create an [`Overlay`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html), though I wouldn't recommend it.

To position the widgets in the overlay correctly, you can use [`CompositedTransformTarget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html) and [`CompositedTransformFollower`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformFollower-class.html)

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can display it as a dialog with the `Colors.black.withOpacity()` property of the Material widget and have it inside of a `GestureDetector` so tapping anywhere on the screen will pop back:

```
static Future<Null> guideDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog<Null>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  "(Tap anywhere to dismiss)",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              //your other widgets to guide here 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: The difficulty is about aligning the tips around the actual buttons.

Comment: Well yes and I can help with that if @Victor G gives more details on how they want it to look but "something like this" wasn't really much to go on. The solution I've provided gives them a template for a guide/walkthrough overlay which they can use to provide their own so I'm not sure why my answer is being downvoted.

Comment: Because the shadow is not even necessary. It could be an arrow or such image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b84ab25a3c565a712b2d291c4053812d442c478e/68747470733a2f2f73746f726167652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f6d6174657269616c2d64657369676e2f7075626c6973682f6d6174657269616c5f765f31322f6173736574732f3042346b762d33755a62533171534738796131527562485252526b452f6578742d7061747465726e732d75736572656475636174696f6e2d30312d696e74726f6e6f77772e706e67

Comment: But the example they've given does use a shadow so that's why I included it? Yes it could be like that image you provided but "something like this" wasn't much to go on and I've shown them how you could implement a guide/walkthrough overlay.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a more generic approach this is why I wasn't too specific. As the screenshot suggests there should some correspondence between the elements in the two layers (i.e. an arrow pointing to the target control)