# Make Shadow on Flutter backdrop

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

how to make appbar lok like is opening a modal?

[image]

picture 1 = what exactly what i want to make

picture 2 = i tried with **showModalBottomSheet** with in case thats not allow me to make it height strecth until appbar

picture 3 = i try with Flutter **Backdrop** its look like what i want, but the appbar cannot like **showModalBottomSheet**,

please help me, how to make the appbar has shadow like showModalBottomSheet does, or how to hack showModalBottomSheet so i can make it height below the appbar?

Comment: you need to create your own page route.
See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908876/7652758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own PageRoute class:

```
class _YourPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  ...
  @override
  bool get opaque => false;
}
```

Now push this route to your navigator:

```
Navigator.push(context, _YourPageRoute(builder: ...));
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908187/how-to-make-a-full-screen-dialog-in-flutter/51908876#51908876) too.