# Flutter : How to disable drag down to close showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to disable  drag down to close the showModalBottomSheet

I have already tried using `enableDrag:false,`

When i'm using `enableDrag:false,` is showing me below error

[image]

Below is my code

```
 modal(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        enableDrag:false,
        isDismissible: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipPath(
                        clipper: OvalTopBorderClipper(),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 440,
                          child: Text("This is a modal bottom sheet !"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 53.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "K",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.textColor, fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border:
                            Border.all(color: AppColors.textColor, width: 2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

I have already check this post

- [Disable drag down to close showModalBottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743566/disable-drag-down-to-close-showmodalbottomsheet)

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you run `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`enableDrag` is not available in `showModalBottomSheet`. I don't think it was ever available in stable channel. According to comments from the link at that time it was available in Master channel. But second answer from that link works well

```
builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
                    onVerticalDragDown: (_) {},
                    child: ...,
```

[here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) is documentation to `showModalBottomSheet` . You can always tap into the `showModalBottomSheet` and customise it.. According to doc

> BottomSheet, which becomes the parent of the widget returned by the function passed as the builder argument to showModalBottomSheet.

and [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) has `enableDrag` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020-05-06 and flutter v1.17.1 enableDrag is available on showModalBottomSheet