# How to prevent bottom sheet dismiss flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to prevent dismissing the `bottom sheet` on swipe down in flutter,
I want to use

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>((BuildContext context) => ...)
```

instead of `showModalBottomSheet` because I need to scaffold information, is there any solution for `showBottomSheet`? how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : How to disable drag down to close showModalBottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861634/flutter-how-to-disable-drag-down-to-close-showmodalbottomsheet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your widget with a `GestureDetector` and disable drag:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(
  (context) => GestureDetector(
    child: YourWidget(),
    onVerticalDragStart: (_) {},
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use `Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>((BuildContext context) => ...)` instead of `showModalBottomSheet` because I need to scaffold information, is there any solution for `showBottomSheet`?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `showModalBottomSheet` use `enableDrag` property.

```
showModalBottomSheet<bool>(
        context: context,
        enableDrag: false,
        ...
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
           return ..your widgets...
        }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isDismissible: false,
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use `Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>((BuildContext context) => ...)` instead of `showModalBottomSheet` because I need to scaffold information, is there any solution for `showBottomSheet`?

Comment: Perfect! lol i forgot this param name

Answer (score 2):

Even though @Sami answer works fine, it's not quite elegant, as it seems like a workaround.

For cases like this, you should use [`AbsorbPointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) instead of just using an empty Gesture.

It's, simply put (pasting the docs):

> A widget that absorbs pointers during hit testing.

In your case, you would use like this:

```dart
Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(
  (context) => AbsorbPointer(child: Container()),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone would like to prevent dismiss bottom sheet from **hardware back button on Android devices**

You have to make your own bottom sheet instead of using showBottomSheet(), like this

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
      return Material(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          },
          child: YourCustomBottomSheet(),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```