# how to make showModalBottomSheet background become pressable

Tags: flutter, dart

just like the title says, when the `showModalBottomSheet` appear i want to press some button in the body/screen without closing the showModalBottomSheet i already set

```
isDismissible: false,
barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
```

but no button can be press

Comment: I suppose you can't. This is why it is called "modal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is to wrap your bottom sheet with a `GestureDetector` and to do some processing in there yourself and avoid the touch event to get to the modal sheet. [Here is a link to a similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62936607/3825725).

From what I understand, `ModalBottomSheet` internally uses `BottomSheet` and its code, where the actual presentation is done looks like this:

```dart
return AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: widget.route!.animation!,
  child: BottomSheet(
    animationController: widget.route!._animationController,
    onClosing: () {
      if (widget.route!.isCurrent) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    },
```

If you look at the `onClosing()` callback, it simply dismisses the object without checking with any external callbacks so I don't really think you can achieve that with a modal bottom sheet in Flutter without wrapping it inside a `GestureDetector`