# Show transparent dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to disply a image in flutter in an transparent dialog. I've set `opaque` to false and used `MaterialType.transparency`. When I open the dialog the background is black.

```
class ShowProfileImage extends ModalRoute<void> {
  final String url;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  VoidCallback onDeleteImage;

  ShowProfileImage(String this.url);

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    // This makes sure that text and other content follows the material style
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
      child: SafeArea(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        width: 300,
                        child: Image(image: NetworkImageWithRetry(url)))))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643972/10711216

Comment: Yes but doesn't work for me.

Comment: showDialog(barrierColor: Colors.transparent, ... )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, here I am showing an image from assets, you can add your code as well if you are fetching from network

```
     showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => new Dialog(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  child: new Container(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    height: 80.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child:  new Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/image.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  ),
                ));
```

Comment: If you do something similar to this and want it to be fully transparent, make sure you set `surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent` on the Dialog and `barrierColor: Colors.transparent` on the showDialog call.

Answer (score 2):

give showDialog a transparent barrierColor that not Colors.transparent,like Color(0x00ffffff)

Answer (score 2):

@TomaVista is right, if you set barrier color transparent, it will cause error,
try Color(0x00ffffff) instead:

```
showDialog(context: context,
    //It doesnt work: barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    barrierColor: Color(0x00ffffff), //this works
    builder: (_) {
      ////
    }
    );
```

Comment: `barrierColor: Colors.transparent` works now with flutter 3.10

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    child: ...
)
```

You must set elevation to 0, otherwise a shadow will be canst beneath the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
_showTransparentDialog(context);
```

Implementation:

```
Future<T> _showTransparentDialog<T>(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog<T>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        content: Image.asset('your_image_asset'),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, And Futter > 3.16, If you have set the background to transparent but still have a shadow color, you need to set `surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent`.

Detail see [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog/surfaceTintColor.html).